# Global switch for functions C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement

I have code like this:

```
  public string ReadName(int ID)
    {
       if(db.Name == "mysql") return mysql.ReadName(ID);
       else if(db.Name == "oracle") return oracle.ReadName(ID);
    }
```

I have many functions like this.
Is there a way that I must not repeat the if-else in every of my functions?

Thank you

Comment: I think it's time you read about inheritance.

Comment: ... and interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

You could define an interface:

```
public interface IMyDb
{
    string ReadName(int ID);
}
```

Then have each database-specific class implement it:

```
public class MySqlDb : IMyDb
{
    public string ReadName(int ID)
    {
        // you have already written the code for this method
    }
}
```

Then when your application initializes, you have a single switch:

```
IMyDb dbImpl;
switch (db.Name)
{
    case "mysql":
        dbImpl = new MySqlDb();
        break;
    case "oracle":
        ...
}
```

And finally you can call the method without having to worry about which class you're using under the hood:

```
string name = dbImpl.ReadName(23);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance:

1. Create base class interface for your database
2. Subclass your database for oracle and mysql
3. Pass your database object to your constructor
4. call database.ReadName(ID);

Answer (score 0):

** Edit: I wrote this before I saw someone answered... any way this is just the same idea with little snippet **

First, you can't solve this problem if you don't know OOP good and inheritance in particular. If oracle and mysql inherit from the same generic type (class or interface), you can just use polymorphism. The best option is keeping a reference to the correct db, and just initialize it in the constructor.

```
public interface DbInterface {
... Generic method declaration
}

public class Mysql :db {
... Generic method implementation
}

public class Oracle :db {
... Generic method implementation
}

public class YourClass {
    private DbInterface _db;

    public YourClass(DbInterface db) {
       this._db = db;
    }
}
```

And then every time you use _db you know for sure it is the db you want.